# Removing unchecked cast warnings with generics

Tags: java, generics, classcastexception, unchecked-cast

I just got into generics with Java, so I set up a little project for myself. I wanted to make a Vector / Point where you could specify the `Number` (e.g. `Double`, `Integer`, `Long`, etc).

I ended up getting a decent class object for it, however noticed some issues regarding the methods.

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;

@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess") // Suppresses weaker access warnings
public class Vector<T extends Number> {

    private T x;
    private T y;

    public Vector() {}

    public Vector(T x, T y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public T getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(T x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public T getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(T y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void dislocate(T offsetX, T offsetY) {
        this.setX(addNumbers(getX(), offsetX));
        this.setY(addNumbers(getY(), offsetY));
    }

    public void dislocate(Vector vector) {
        this.setX(addNumbers(getX(), vector.getX()));
        this.setY(addNumbers(getY(), vector.getY()));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // Suppresses cast unchecked warnings
    private T addNumbers(Number... numbers) {
        BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(0);

        for(Number number : numbers) {
            bd = bd.add(new BigDecimal(number.toString()));
        }

        return (T) bd;
    }
}
```

The final method, which is the adding numbers method, throws an unchecked cast warning. After I did some research, I figured out it was behaving oddly due to generics, which I'm relatively new in and unable to properly troubleshoot.

What about `return (T) bd;` creates the warning? `T` has to be an instance of a `Number`, so it should be cast-able to a `BigDecimal`, right?

So I created my little testing method,

```
Vector<Double> vec = new Vector<>(1.0, 3.0);
Vector<Double> vec2 = new Vector<>(2.2, 3.9);
vec.dislocate(1.0, 2.7);
System.out.println(vec.getX() + " " + vec.getY());
vec.dislocate(vec2);
System.out.println(vec.getX() + " " + vec.getY());
```

It works great, printing out `2.0 5.7` and `4.2 9.6`.

The issue then, is when I use a method from `Double`, like `Double#isNaN()`. It then throws out the ClassCastException, `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.base/java.lang.Double`.

This seemed pretty common with other issues people have had with this, however, despite going over the resources, I don't understand *why* the error is thrown using the `Double` methods. The object should be a `Double` after the cast, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, you need to provide some means of adding `T`s.

For example, a `BinaryOperator<T>` is something that takes in two `T`s, and returns a `T`. So, you can define ones for adding, for example:

```
BinaryOperator<Double> addDoubles = (a, b) -> a+b;
BinaryOperator<BigDecimal> addBigDecimals = (a, b) -> a.add(b);
```

Now, you actually need to supply an instance of this to your Vector when you create it, e.g. as a constructor parameter:

```
public Vector(BinaryOperator<T> adder) {
  this.adder = adder; // define a field, too.
}
```

And now use the BiFunction to add the numbers:

```
private T addNumbers(T a, T b) {
  return adder.apply(a, b); // or you could just invoke this directly.
}
```

I simplified your `addNumbers` always to take two parameters, since you only invoke with two parameters. To do it generically, you'd either need to provide a "generic zero", i.e. a value of type T which is zero for that type, or simply to start from the first element in the varargs array.

Comment: Looking at the interface of `Number` we could provide an addition `BiFunction` for every primitive type. But since `Number` isn't final there might be other subclasses  which need dedicated addition `BiFunction`s.  Thus this approach will work for primitive types and known subtypes of `Number`. So if we know what we are dealing with this approach will work. (+1)

Comment: The only issue here is that the `BiFunction<T>` returns this error in the IDE: `Wrong number of type arguments: 1; required: 3`, so `BiFunction<T>` sadly doesn't work.

Comment: You're right. It should be `BeFunction<T,T,T>` since the `adder` has to add two instance of the type `T` which is the generic type of the `Vector<T>`. The third `T`is the result type of the `adder`. It has to be `T` too in order to store the result  in the `Vector<T>`.

Comment: @VeeAyeInIn misremembered the API. I meant `BinaryOperator<T>` (which is a subinterface of `BinaryFunction<T, T, T>`).

Comment: @AndyTurner Well even with the `BinaryFunction<T, T, T>`, that helped me a long ways, as I got this: https://hastebin.com/azafobefum.java , which I am rather happy about.

Answer (score 3):

You basically can't do things like this in Java.  `(T) someBigDecimal` will work if and only if `T` is a `BigDecimal` itself.  The way erasure works may hide that from you temporarily, but `Number` has *no* special magic about being able to add two Numbers or cast one to another.

In general, there's not really *any* way to generify in Java over different kinds of numbers and then be able to do numerical things with them.

Answer (score 1):

> The object should be a Double after the cast, right?

Never because casting (with or without generics) never changes the runtime type. It just changes the declared type that you manipulate.

In `addNumbers()` you actually perform an uncheck casts : `BigDecimal` to `T`.
The compiler warns you of the uncheck cast but accepts it as `BigDecimal` is compatible with `T` that has as upper-bounded wildcard : `Number`.
The contained elements of the generic class instance :

```
private T x;
private T y;
```

refer now the `BigDecimal` type and no more `Double` type.